# Multiple field seperators each of which appears multiple times using awk

Tags: unix, awk, delimiter

I am trying to separate fields using awk but have met some problems when I have multiple separators each of which appears multiple times.

For example, if I type

```
echo "aa@@#####=#3413.5" | awk -F "#+|@+|=" '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}'
```

then the results are:

```
aa,,,,3413.5
```

but what I want is

```
aa,3413.5
```

I have searched online for a long time, but other questions are related to either multiple separators appearing one time for each, i.e. "@|#", or a single separator appearing multiple times, i.e. "@+".

Anyone has ideas about how to separate fields in my case?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I couldn't get the question, but isn't `awk -F '[@#=]+'` sufficient ?

Comment: @ymonad This works for me! Thanks a lot! But I don't quite understand why "#+|@+|=" not working..

Comment: I would write it to answer section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F '[@#=]+'
```

seems to work.

```
awk -F "#+|@+|="
```

this one matches only for string like `#####`, `@@@@`,  or `=`.

see following URL for detail:

http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html#SEC28

Comment: Thanks for the link. For the "#+|@+|=" case, my string will be separated into 5 fields but $2~$4 are empty, which makes it a little weird.

Comment: if FS is "#+|@+|=", awk splits "aa@@#####=#3413.5" to  `aa` `@@` `<empty>` `#####`  `<empty>` `=` `<empty>` `#` `3413.5` , so $2~$4 will be empty.